# Could not load file or assembly rdlc VS 2017

Tags: c#, dll, rdlc

I am using Visual Studio 2017 for developing rdlc and using a localization project which is a part of my solution. I create a DLL out of this localization project and use the code in the DLL in the Report code. 
I reference this DLL and I am getting this error in the rdlc.

```
Error while loading code module: ‘MyDll, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null’. Details: Could not load file or assembly 'MyDll, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I tried to copy this DLL to few locations such as, but it did not work.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies
```

I also ran `gacutil -i MyDll.dll` but that still does not work.

What could be wrong here?

Comment: It compiles? Do you have that DLL on gac or working directory? Can you attach a debugger to process ?

Comment: It does not compile.. dll is in working directory and the locations I mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out a location where dll needs to be put in using the assembly binding log viewer and here is it,

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin

Now its working fine.

Comment: I am glad i found your post.
Do you think it has something to do with one of the latest VS updates? I can't remember having this issue before..